# React component method this.state.myState undefined after returning from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a Parent component (`BookApplication`) and a child component (`SearchBox`) in React. The SearchBox has an input field, and should give the input back to the parent for handling the event. That is working fine, but when i am back in the parent component in the method `handleSearch` the `this.state...` is undefined.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'books' of undefined
```

But searchInput has the value it should have.
But i need the books from this.state.books again :/ 
I understand that in the method `handleSearch` i am working in it's scope, so `this....` is the context of handleSearch... but how do i get the arguments of it's component the `BookApplication` again? 
I am still learning javascript, and i thought this shouldnt be a problem, because a function can always use the variables of it's parent object?

```
class BookApplication extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {books: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.get(PATH, function (result) {
            this.setState({
                books: result
            });
        }.bind(this));
    }

    handleSearch(searchInput) {
        //Sort the books list
        var sortedList = [];
        this.state.books.map(
            function (currentBook) {
                currentBook.keys().forEach(
                    function (key, pos) {
                        if (key.contains(searchInput)) {
                            sortedList.push(currentBook)
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        );
    }

render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBox onSearch={this.handleSearch}/>
                <div className="book-list">
                    {this.state.books.map(function (currentBook) {
                        return <Book book={currentBook} key={currentBook.id}/>;
                    }) }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Here also my SearchBox:

```
class SearchBox extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {searchFieldInput: ''};
    this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSearchChange(event) {
    this.setState({searchFieldInput: event.target.value});
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    //Prevent the browser's defeault action of submitting the form
    e.preventDefault();

    var searchFieldInput = this.state.searchFieldInput.trim();
    //Call the passed callback function
    this.props.onSearch({searchFieldInput: searchFieldInput});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="book-search">
            <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.searchFieldInput}
                onChange={this.handleSearchChange}
                placeholder="Search..."
                className="search-bar"
            />
            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="search-button">Search</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: looks like someone directly manipulating state rather setState

Comment: i was working with the [facebook tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) itself! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to get parent's context from child component, then try

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
    ...
    clickHandler(event){}

    render(){
        <ChildComponent parent={this}/>
    }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        let parent = this.props.parent;
        return <button onClick={parent.clickHandler}></button>
    }
}
```

And you will get an error here

```
componentDidMount() {
    $.get(PATH, function (result) {
        this.setState({
            books: result
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Because `this` in the callback function not referred to your Component's context. You should keep component's context in variable

```
componentDidMount() {
    let self = this;
    $.get(PATH, function (result) {
        self.setState({
            books: result
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Finally decision is

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {books: []};
    //add the following line into your code
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: no i am already back in the parent component in it's method `handleSearch` with the input of the child component. But the parents state seems not longer available.
I need the `this.state.books` again that i loaded in the beginning.

Comment: But i do not get an error in the componentDidMount method... The REST works absolutely fine. 
When my app starts, i load the books and show them (with this.state.books). That works without problems. Than i write an String to search for in my nested input field (the SearchComponent). When i return from the search component back to the parent component i cannot get the books again from this.state.books

Comment: Add the following line `this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this)` into your `constructor`